# Consuming a WSDL from a Flex client with inheritance types

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, inheritance, actionscript, jaxb

General information:

- I use Flex 4.5
- I use FlashBuilder 4
- I generate the WSDL using JAX-WS 2.2 (via a GlassFish 3.1 AS)

I want to have a web service that returns a list of clients.
In the Java code, I have a base class for a Client, and 2 extending classes:

```
public class Client {
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

public class AdvisedClient extends Client {
    public String getFoo() {
        return this.foo;
    }
}

public class NotAdvisedClient extends Client {
    public String getBar() {
        return this.bar;
    }
}
```

These classes are POJOs.

The web service looks like this:

```
public class ClientsModel {
    public List<Client> getClients() {
        return this.clients;
    }
}

 @WebService
public class ClientService {
    @WebMethod
    public ClientsModel getClients(String bla) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I tried to use the following methods for representing the inheritance in the eventual WSDL:

http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html

(Here I annotated all 3 classes with @XmlRootElement, I also annotated ClientsModel with @XmlRootElement, annotated the ClientsModel.getClients() with @XmlElementRef, and also annotated ClientsModel with @XmlSeeAlso so that the JAXBContext would recognize the AdvisedClient and NotAdvisedClient classes).

http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-xsitype.html

(Here I annotated only the Client class with @XmlRootElement, and left the extending classes as is, and also removed the @XmlElementRef annotation).

For the first approach (substitution), I got the following schema:

```
<xs:complexType name="ClientsModel">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element ref="tns:AdvisedClient" /> 
      <xs:element ref="tns:NotAdvisedClient" /> 
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="Client">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="AdvisedClient">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="tns:Client">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="foo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
      </xs:sequence>  
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="NotAdvisedClient">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="tns:Client">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="bar" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
      </xs:sequence>  
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

And when I used FlashBuilder's 'Connect to Web Service' wizard, I got a ClientsModel class which contains a property for advisedClient and another for notAdvisedClient, but NOT as lists!

Then I tried the 2nd approach, and got the following schema:

```
<xs:complexType name="ClientsModel">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="clients" type="tns:Client" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
   </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Whereas the complexType for Client, AdvisedClient and NotAdvisedClient remained the same.

After generating the classes in ActionScript using FlashBuilder, I this time got only Client class binded, with no AdvisedClient or NotAdvisedClient...

Is there another way to control the schema using JAXB, so that the inherit

---

Thanks for the answer, to start with.

Sorry for not being more specific about the AS generated classes.
I didn't mean lists per-se. I meant the idea that generated ClientsModel class does not contain a List/array/ArrayCollection and so on. It contains a single property for an AdvisedClient and a single for NotAdvisedClient.

The generated class is quite complex, but I will try to simplify it:

```
public class _Super_ClientsModel extends flash.events.EventDispatcher implements com.adobe.fiber.valueobjects.IValueObject {
    private var _internal_client : com.company.product.clients.valueObjects.Client;
    private var _internal_advisedClient : com.company.product.clients.valueObjects.AdvisedClient;
    private var _internal_notAdvisedClient : com.company.product.clients.valueObjects.NotAdvisedClient;       
}
```

The get functions return them respectively.

So you see that the generated class is not as I would expect, and it's nothing I can work with.
If you think that the whole class is relevant here, I could attach it too...

Thanks again,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

```
when I used FlashBuilder's 'Connect to Web Service' wizard, I got a ClientsModel class which contains a property for advisedClient and another for notAdvisedClient, but NOT as lists!
```

A [List](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/List.html) in Flex is a UI element, and it not usually used as a data type for passing information to and from a remote service.  I would not expect anything model style objects that Flash Builder automatically generates to generate anything with a "List" data type.  It would more likely use an Array or ArrayCollection.

But, you didn't show the generated AS3 objects; nor did you specify what they were being generated as; so I'm not sure where to direct you next.